# How to show $ax^t+by^t\le (ax+by)^t.$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $0<a,b,t<1$ and $x,y>0$. Show that 
$$ax^t+by^t\le (ax+by)^t.$$

I want to use this for a step in another proof. I've convinced myself it is correct since I have yet to find a counter example. My question is, how can I prove this inequality? I have tried directly and by contradiction, but I get no where.

Comment: @MostafaAyaz: Why did you change $ax^t+by^t$ to $(ax)^t + (by)^t$ ???

Comment: Because in that case the inequality doesn't hold.....

Comment: This is equivalent to $u^t+v^t\le(u+v)^t$ with $t\in(0,1)$ and $u,v>0$, isn't it? No sense in using five variables when three would do.

Comment: It seems to me you have the inequality flipped. The statement is true for $u^t + v^t \geq (u + v)^t$, using @TonyK's notation.

Comment: I have rolled back the edit. It is not our task to guess what the real question is.

Comment: @MartinR Choose $a=b$, and $x=y$. You get $2a\le (2a)^t$, which is not always true

Comment: @Andrei: Sure, but $(ax)^t + (by)^t \le (ax+by)^t$ isn't always true either. What sense does it make to edit the question and replace one wrong statement by another wrong statement (without any input from the question author)?

Comment: Well I've already posted and deleted an answer due to the question being edited. I'm not going to delete my comment too, due to the question being edited back. @MostafaAyaz, I'm looking at you!

Comment: What I am taking away from this discussion is that my inequality is not true. This explains why I failed to prove it.

Answer (score 0):

This expands on the comments, particularly by TonyK:

Let $t\in(0,1)$, and set $f(x)=x^t$.  Note that $f'(x)=tx^{t-1}$ and $f''(x)=t(t-1)x^{t-2}$.  For $x>0$, note that $f''(x)<0$.  Hence $f(x)$ is [concave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concave_function).  Since also $f(0)\ge 0$, this means that $f(x)$ is [subadditive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subadditivity). This means that $$f(u+v)\le f(u)+f(v)$$
Now, setting $u=ax, v=by$, we get
$$f(ax+by)\le f(ax)+f(by)$$
or $$(ax+by)^t\le (ax)^t+(by)^t$$

Comments:  This only requires $a,x,b,y>0$, not necessarily in $(0,1)$.  Also, this is reversed from the original inequality posted, and includes parentheses not present in the original question.